# making link lists as columns automatically css

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am using `wp_list_pages($args);` to display menu in my wordpress site. I need to display  all links as three columns automatically. The links should wrap into three columns automatically like the following.

[image]

How can i achieve this using css?

Answer (score 0):

Change values accordingly.

http://jsfiddle.net/TABVe/

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
<a href="#">test link</a>
<a href="#">test link</a>
<a href="#">test link</a>
<a href="#">test link</a>
<a href="#">test link</a>
<a href="#">test link</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
.menu a {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
width: 60px;
}
.menu a:nth-child(3n) {
margin-right: 0px;
clear: right;
}
```